# Filter all posts by a certain ID

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I currently view all threads with

```
allthreads = Threads.query.order_by(Threads.date_created).all()
return render_template('reply.html', allthreads = allthreads, thread=thread, tsc=tsc)
```

I can then iterate trough them in my index.html like this:

```
        {% for allthreads in allthreads %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ allthreads.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ allthreads.username }}</td>
        <td>{{ allthreads.content }}</td>
        <td>{{ allthreads.date_created.date() }}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="/reply/{{allthreads.id}}">Reply</a>
            <br>
            <a href="/delete/{{allthreads.id}}">Delete</a>
            <br>
            <a href="/update/{{allthreads.id}}">Update</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Now when i click on a thread i only want to see that thread and the posts that have the specific thread_ID which corresponds to the ID of the thread.

Its already storing the Threads in the Threads table and the replies in the Posts table and its assigning the IDs correspondingly.

What i dont understand is how to filter to only view the relevant Thread and the belonging posts. The variable id contains the correct ID.

```
current_thread = Threads.query().filter(Threads.id == id)
relevant_replies = Posts.query().filter(Threads.id == id)
tsc = len(allposts)
return render_template('reply.html', allposts=allposts, relevant_replies= relevant_replies thread=thread, tsc=tsc)
```

How can i only get the SQL entries with the ID that's in the variable `id`?

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the posts from the thread, you'd need to join `Posts` to `Threads`, or (if it's present) use `Post.thread_id == id`.

```
relevant_replies = Posts.query.join(Threads, <some join condition>).filter(Threads.id == id)
```

Most likely, `Posts` has a `thread_id` property, though. See also [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html) for more information.